# How to navigate through <li> elements using arrow keys - jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to navigate between list items with the following structure using keyboard arrow keys - help appreciated

I rather not paste my own code here as it has a lot of attributes that is not have anything to do with the problem. I could possibly add a class on each selected item?

```
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="card-list">
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item1</li>            
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item2</li>            
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item3</li>            
           </a>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="card-list">
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item3</li>            
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item4</li>            
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item5</li>            
           </a>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck! *(Not my downvote)*

Comment: What do you mean you are trying to navigate between list items? You are trying to highlight them in the browser and move between them using arrow keys?

Comment: @RegSmith that's correct

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to reflect that clarification for other users? I think my answer is what you are looking for, let me know if you need anymore help.

Answer (score 7):

Place all the `li` elements into a collection and set up a tracking variable.
Then set up a `keydown` event handler for the document that alters the tracker variable based on which key was pressed and apply styling to the element that has an index in its collect that matches the tracking variable.

See comments inline below for details:

```js
// Get all the <li> elements into a collection
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".card-list li");

// Set up a counter to keep track of which <li> is selected
var currentLI = 0;

// Initialize first li as the selected (focused) one:
listItems[currentLI].classList.add("highlight");

// Set up a key event handler for the document
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
  // Check for up/down key presses
  switch(event.keyCode){
    case 38: // Up arrow    
      // Remove the highlighting from the previous element
      listItems[currentLI].classList.remove("highlight");
      
      currentLI = currentLI > 0 ? --currentLI : 0;     // Decrease the counter      
      listItems[currentLI].classList.add("highlight"); // Highlight the new element
      break;
    case 40: // Down arrow
      // Remove the highlighting from the previous element
      listItems[currentLI].classList.remove("highlight");
      
      currentLI = currentLI < listItems.length-1 ? ++currentLI : listItems.length-1; // Increase counter 
      listItems[currentLI].classList.add("highlight");       // Highlight the new element
      break;    
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight { background-color:#ff0; }
```

```html
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="card-list">
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item1</li>            
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item2</li>            
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item3</li>            
           </a>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="card-list">
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item3</li>            
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item4</li>            
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item5</li>            
           </a>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague, without seeing what you have done I can only recommend that you should look into the use of Javascript and the onkeypress() event handler.

You can get a list of your `<a>` tags by giving them all a class, lets call it "cardATags".

```
var aList = document.querySelectorAll(".cardATags");
```

We will start the page at an index of 0.

```
var index = 0;
```

and set them to the currently focused item with something like

```
aList[index].focus();
```

Now in your `onkeypress()` event handler you can increment the index and set the next focused item.

Good luck.

A bit of clarification, add classes to your code like so:

```
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="card-list">
           <a class="cardATags" href="#">
             <li>Card Item1</li>            
           </a>
           <a class="cardATags" href="#">
             <li>Card Item2</li>            
           </a>
           <a class="cardATags" href="#">
             <li>Card Item3</li>            
           </a>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="card-list">
           <a class="cardATags" href="#">
             <li>Card Item3</li>            
           </a>
           <a class="cardATags" href="#">
             <li>Card Item4</li>            
           </a>
           <a class="cardATags" href="#">
             <li>Card Item5</li>            
           </a>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *you can set an id on each of the cards and have a function which can move through the ids* Better yet, put all the `li` elements into an array and just advance through the elements in the array by their index numbers.

Comment: Let him walk before he runs.

Comment: There's nothing that's more complex about using an array than using `id`s. In fact, the array solution is simpler.

Comment: A couple of things though. `getElementsByClassName()` returns a "live" node list and, in most cases, that isn't needed. Live node lists hurt performance. `.querySelectorAll()` should generally be used. Also, `li` elements don't have a `focus()` method because they are not focusable elements.

Comment: That is just a bad variable name, I specified that the class should be put on his <a> tags. I will change the variable name and specify the querySelectorAll instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about when you talk about the variable name. I didn't mention anything about your variable name. Besides, `.querySelectorAll()`, I said that `<li>` elements don't have a `.focus()` method.

Comment: I called the variable liList, but it was actually a list of the anchor tags.

Comment: I wasn't referring to that. I was talking about actual `li` elements. You can't call `.focus()` on them - they are not focusable.

Comment: You're right, that is why I am focusing the <a> tags.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('li').eq(0).addClass('active')
$('.cardATags').eq(0).focus();


$(document).keydown(function(e) {
   var li_count=$('li').length;
   var curent_active=0;

   var each_counter=0;
   $('li').each(function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass('active')){
            curent_active=each_counter;
        }
        each_counter++;
   });

  if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
    curent_active-=1;
  }else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
     curent_active+=1;
  }if(e.keyCode == 38) {  // top
    curent_active-=1;
  }if(e.keyCode == 40) {  // bott
    curent_active+=1;
  }

  if(curent_active==li_count){
     curent_active=0;
  }

  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $('li').eq(curent_active).addClass('active');

});
```

```css
   .active{
      background-color:gray;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


Press UP or DOWN or LEFT or RIGHT arrows...


<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="card-list">
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item1</li>
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item2</li>
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item3</li>
           </a>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="card-list">
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item3</li>
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item4</li>
           </a>
           <a href="#">
             <li>Card Item5</li>
           </a>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are looking for, but someone else may find my solution helpful. Given the following list:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="my_ul" >
  <li tabindex="0"> <a href="#"> Project 1 </a> </li>
  <li tabindex="0"> <a href="#"> Project 2 </a> </li>
  <li tabindex="0"> <a href="#"> Project 3 </a> </li>
</ul>
```

There were 2 things I needed to do to get this working:

1. add `tabindex="0"` to each of the `<li>` - this allows the list element to be focusable (and thus allowing you to use the arrow keys to navigate)
2. I used jQuery on a down arrow event to move the focus on to the first `<a>` tag of the first `<li>` of the wrapper `<ul>` e.g. `jQuery("#my_ul > li > a").first().focus();` (where *my_ul* is the id of the wrapper `<ul>`). In my case, unlike yours, I put the `<a>` tags inside the `<li>` - not sure if that makes a difference, but thought it worth mentioning.